# Items customization in e-commerce platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, e-commerce

I'm building a simple e-commerce platform in Rails for restaurants to facilitate online ordering. What I want to do is let a `restaurant` customize each one of its `items` independently. For example, said restaurant may want to add a `size` to one `item` with an added charge for different sizes, or a `flavor` to another `item`, or any arbitrary attribute; also, different items won't necessarily have the same attributes. So basically, I want to let restaurants add custom fields when they create items.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Postgres 9.2+ as database backend you can achieve you goal easily.

Enable [hstore extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/hstore.html) (this also can be done via SQL).

```
class AddExtrasToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension "hstore"
    add_column :items, :extras, :hstore
    # I also advice to use gin for indexing 
    # add_index :users, :extras, using: :gin
  end
end
```

[Might be helpful - GIN and GIST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch-indexes.html)

The identify this property (`extras`) with `store_accessor` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :extras
  ...
end
```

Then you'll be able to create records, such

```
i1 = Item.new
i1.name = 'foo'
i1.type = 'salad'
i1.extras = { size: 'big', vegan: 'yes' }
i1.save

i2 = Item.new
i2.name = 'bar'
i2.type = 'snack'
i2.extras = { flavor: 'mexicana', kosher: 'yes' }
i2.save
```

Querying

```
# Items having flavor
Item.where("extras ? :key", key: "flavor") 

# Items classified as kosher
Item.where("extras @> hstore(:key, :value)",
  key: "kosher", value: "yes"
)
```

BTW postgres also have json and jsonb column types to store documents inside your database. They also might be useful - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [document oriented databases/NOSQL systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database), like [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/)